# Blog Overflow comment responses are outdented instead of indented

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog, blog-overflow

Check out the [responses to comments](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/04/jesus-is-lord-and-other-hobbies/#comments).

They're misaligned and cut off on account of the `margin-left: -20px important;`

Comment: Does this mean my comment was `important`?  I'm flattered.

Comment: `Important` enough to have the first few letters cut off (well at least you can figure out how to reply, that last comment of mine was supposed to be a reply to you)

Comment: So now Affable Geek and El'endia Starman have `important` comments too?  I feel a third less special. :-(

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this has been deployed.  The comments are now correctly indented.

(: