# Author reply comment cut off on left

Tags: bug, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blog Overflow comment responses are outdented instead of indented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134508/blog-overflow-comment-responses-are-outdented-instead-of-indented)

If you look at Martha F's (the author) comment on [Seasoned Advice Blog: How to experiment with a dish: What I learned this Shavuot](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/how-to-experiment-with-a-dish-what-i-learned-this-shavuot/#comments), her comment is cut off on the left. I have checked this in Firefox 12 and also in Chrome. It appears this way for other people, too:

[image: Screenshot of Martha F's post, showing left edge cut off]

The "S" and "s" have been cut off, on the left.